# wpf wait animation acceleration ColorAnimation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I found pretty nice wait animation control (http://pastebin.com/HtVyNpxc). But there is a problem that it heavily load the system. And it is because of using many ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames. Does anybody know how to improve it? Maybe using just  1 ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.

```
<UserControl
x:Class="LoadingControl.Control.WA"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
mc:Ignorable="d" 
IsHitTestVisible="False"
>
<UserControl.Resources>

    <Geometry x:Key="Block">
        M291.15499,85.897525
        C291.15499,85.897525
         301.88917,85.87921
         301.88917,85.87921
         301.88917,85.87921
         300.38339,94.355061
         300.38339,94.355061
         300.38339,94.355061
         292.85366,94.355042
         292.85366,94.355042
         292.85366,94.355042
         291.15499,85.897525
         291.15499,85.897525
        Z
    </Geometry>

    <!-- Animations for the individual blocks of the progress ring -->
    <Storyboard x:Key="ProgressAnimation" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="00:00:03.6">

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.4" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#FF000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#00000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#0C000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#0C000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#19000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#19000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#26000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.8" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#26000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#3D000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.8" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.0" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#3D000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#56000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.0" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.2" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#56000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block7" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#63000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.2" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.4" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#63000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#72000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.4" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="#FF000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#72000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block9" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#7F000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.6" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.8" Value="#FF000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#7F000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block10" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#8E000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.8" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="#FF000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#8E000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block11" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#9B000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.2" Value="#FF000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#9B000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block12" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#AA000000"/>               
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.2" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.4" Value="#FF000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#AA000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block13" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#B7000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.4" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.6" Value="#FF000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#B7000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block14" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#C6000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.6" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8" Value="#FF000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#C6000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block15" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#D3000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.8" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.0" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#D3000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block16" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#E2000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.0" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.2" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#E2000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03.6" Storyboard.TargetName="block17" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.OpacityMask).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0" Value="#EF000000"/>                
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.2" Value="#00000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.4" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03.6" Value="#EF000000"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>

</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard
            x:Name="ProgressAnimation_BeginStoryboard"
            Storyboard="{StaticResource ProgressAnimation}"
        />
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>

<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="88" Width="88">

    <Grid Width="10.734" Height="10.004" Canvas.Left="38.614" Canvas.Top="0.331">

        <!-- Block 0 -->
        <Path x:Name="block0" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#00000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 1 -->
        <Path x:Name="block1" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#0C000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-160"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 2 -->
        <Path x:Name="block2" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#19000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-140"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 3 -->
        <Path x:Name="block3" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#26000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-120"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 4 -->
        <Path x:Name="block4" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#3D000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-100"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 5 -->
        <Path x:Name="block5" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#56000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-80"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 6 -->
        <Path x:Name="block6" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#64000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-60"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 7 -->
        <Path x:Name="block7" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#72000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-40"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 8 -->
        <Path x:Name="block8" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#80000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-20"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 9 -->
        <Path x:Name="block9" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" OpacityMask="#8E000000" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 10 -->
        <Path x:Name="block10" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#9C000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="20"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 11 -->
        <Path x:Name="block11" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#AA000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="40"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 12 -->
        <Path x:Name="block12" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#B8000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="60"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 13 -->
        <Path x:Name="block13" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#C6000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="80"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 14 -->
        <Path x:Name="block14" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#D4000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="100"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 15 -->
        <Path x:Name="block15" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#E2000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="120"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 16 -->
        <Path x:Name="block16" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="#F0000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="140"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

        <!-- Block 17 -->
        <Path x:Name="block17" Fill="#FF5482A1" Stretch="Fill" Data="{StaticResource Block}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,4.3689" OpacityMask="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10.004">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="160"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>

    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its just a loading `Animation` and your doing background work you could try dropping the framerate of the `Animation` from 60fps to 30fps using the `TimeLine` `AttachedProperty`. This should improve the speed/responsiveness of the `Animation` while your background task is running

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="ProgressAnimation" Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="30" ...........
```

Also it would be a good idea to `Resource` all the common `Brushes` into a single `StaticResource` brush so it doen not need to create the same brush multiple times